# Retrofit 2 response body to custom class

Tags: java, kotlin, retrofit2

Currently, I use [retrofit2](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) to call restful apis and get response. Because the response body can be multiple types, I wrote the code following.

```
//Interface
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("payments/events/{id}")
fun postPayment(@Path("id") id: String): Call<Any>

//Api Manager
fun postPayment(id: String): Observable<Any> {
    return Observable.create {
        subscriber ->
        val callResponse = api.postPayment(id)
        val response = callResponse.execute()

        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            if (response.body() is MyClass1) {
                // never success... 
            } else if (response.body() is MyClass2) {
                // never success...
            }
            subscriber.onNext(response.body())
            subscriber.onCompleted()
        } else {
            subscriber.onError(Throwable(response.message()))
        }
    }
}
```

So I'm not able to cast `response.body()` to `MyClass1` or `MyClass2`.
`response.body() as MyClass1` occurs error too.

`MyClass1` and `MyClass2` are normal template classes.

```
class MyClass1( val id: String, val data: String)
```

Is there any smart way to cast response body to my custom classes?

**Small update for MyClass2**

```
class MyClass2( val token: String, val url: String, val quantity: Int)
```

Comment: Why don't you use a custom object for receiving your response? something like `Call<MyResponse>`

Comment: As I described, in my case the response type can be multiple types - MyClass1 or MyClass2.

Comment: Are there (`MyClass1` and `MyClass2`) too much different?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes.

Comment: Retrofit knows nothing about `MyClass1` and `MyClass2`, you may want to write a custom responseBodyConverter.

Comment: @Igor Can you show the code for `MyClass2`?

Comment: Sure, just a moment.

Comment: Updated for MyClass2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, thanks @Bryan for answer. Your answer was perfect but finally I did something tricky way.

```
...
if (response.isSuccessful) {
    val jsonObject = JSONObject(response.body() as Map<*, *>)
    val jsonString = jsonObject.toString()
    if (jsonObject.has("id")) {
        val myclass1Object = Gson().fromJson(jsonString, MyClass1::class.java)
        ...
    } else {
        val myclass2Object = Gson().fromJson(jsonString, MyClass2::class.java)
        ...
    }
}
...
```

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by @Miha_x64, Retrofit doesn't know about your classes (`MyClass1` and `MyClass2`) because your `Call` uses the `Any` type. Therefore, Retrofit is not creating an instance of `MyClass1` or `MyClass2`, instead it is just creating an instance of the `Any` class.

The simplest solution would just be to combine the two classes:

```
data class MyClass(
    val id: String?,
    val data: String?,
    val token: String?,
    val url: String?,
    val quantity: Int
)
```

Then you can specify the response type in your interface:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("payments/events/{id}")
fun postPayment(@Path("id") id: String): Call<MyClass>
```

In the case your response does not have an `id` or `data` element, they will just be `null`. Then you can check which type of response was received simply by checking which values are `null`:

```
if (response.body().id != null) {
    // Handle type 1 response...
} else if (response.body().token != null) {
    // Handle type 2 response...
}
```

---

A slightly more complex solution would be to write a wrapper for your two classes, and a type adapter to populate the wrapper. This would avoid the nullability of each of the fields, as well as keep your data structure separated.

This would differ based on the `ConverterFactory` you are using but if, for example, you are using Gson, it would look something like this:

```
data class ApiResponse(
    val val1: MyClass1? = null,
    val val2: MyClass2? = null
)

class ApiResponseAdapter : TypeAdapter<ApiResponse> {

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun write(out: JsonWriter, value: ApiResponse?) {
        if (value != null) {
            out.beginObject()

            value.val1?.id? let { out.name("id").value(it) }
            value.val1?.data? let { out.name("data").value(it) }
            value.val2?.token? let { out.name("token").value(it) }
            value.val2?.url? let { out.name("url").value(it) }
            value.val2?.quantity? let { out.name("quantity").value(it) }

            out.endObject()
        } else {
            out.nullValue()
        }
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun read(in: JsonReader): ApiResponse {
        reader.beginObject()

        var id: String? = null
        var data: String? = null
        var token: String? = null
        var url: String? = null
        var quantity: Int = 0

        while(in.hasNext()) {
            val name = in.nextName()

            if (name.equals("id", true)) {
                id = in.nextString()
            } else if (name.equals("data", true)) {
                data = in.nextString()
            } else if (name.equals("token", true)) {
                token = in.nextString()
            } else if (name.equals("url", true)) {
                url = in.nextString()
            } else if (name.equals("quantity", true)) {
                quantity = in.nextInt()
            }
        }

        reader.endObject()

        if (id != null && data != null) {
            return ApiResponse(MyClass1(id, data), null)
        } else if (token != null && url != null) {
            return ApiResponse(null, MyClass2(token, url, quantity))
        } else {
            return ApiResponse()
        }
    }

}
```

Then you can add this type adapter to your Gson instance:

```
val gson = GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(ApiResponse::class.java, ApiResponseAdapter()).create()
```

Then replace the `Call<Any>` type with `Call<ApiRepsone>` and you can then check which response was received by checking which value is `null`:

```
if (response.body().val1 != null) {
    // Handle MyClass1 response...
} else if (response.body().val2 != null) {
    // Handle MyClass2 response...
}
```